# Finding x axis locations for conditional y values

Tags: r, statistics, signal-processing

I have about 180000 data points that look like this - [Figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isvhE.png). Its 0's and 5's at irregular intervals.

```
data<- 0,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,0,0.. and so on.
```

I want to find indices where the starting and end y values are 5 (ones marked in blue). The graph is attached in the figure. I am using R to do the analysis. I tried using the `cpt.meanvar` function in the `changepoint` package, but it doesn't give all the change point locations. Is there another method?

Comment: This is not quite clear.  Your `data` variable seems to be y, but what is x?  the index?   What would be the answer for the above small bit of data? Would it be starts = c(4,10)  ends = c(6, 12)?

Answer (score 2):

```
#DATA
mydata<- c(0,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,0,0)

#Find out which indices have 5
v = which(mydata == 5)

#Split into groups of consecutive integers and get the range for each sub-group
lapply(split(v, cumsum(c(1, diff(v) != 1))), function(x) range(x))
#$`1`
#[1] 4 6

#$`2`
#[1] 10 12
```

Putting in `data.frame` may be more easier

```
setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(v, cumsum(c(1, diff(v) != 1))),
                                          function(x) range(x)))),
         c("Start", "End"))
#  Start End
#1     4   6
#2    10  12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for